# Drag and drop positioning problems+ updating the id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Hello my stackoverflow friends. I have some problems today and need your help to solve them. If you can help with anything it would be much appreciated! Because I really need to finish this project.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdxmmobe/1/

**This is the script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$(".DraggedItem").draggable({
        helper:'clone', 
        cursor:'move',
        opacity: 0.7
});

$('#rang1').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#rang1input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});

$('#rang2').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#rang2input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});

$('#rang3').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#rang3input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});

$('#rang4').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#rang4input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});

$('#rang5').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#rang5input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});

$('#rang6').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#rang6input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});

$('#rang7').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $('#rang7input').val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
});
}); 
</script>
```

**These are the 7 droppable divs (where you can drop images):**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["IDBewoner"] ?>" name="bewoner">
<td> 
    <div id="rang1"></div> 
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang1input" name="rang1value">
</td>
<td> 
    <div id="rang2"></div> 
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang2input" name="rang2value">
</td>
<td> 
    <div id="rang3"></div> 
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang3input" name="rang3value">
</td>
<td> 
    <div id="rang4"></div> 
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang4input" name="rang4value">
</td>
<td> 
    <div id="rang5"></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang5input" name="rang5value">
</td>
<td> 
    <div id="rang6"></div> 
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang6input" name="rang6value">
</td>
<td> 
    <div id="rang7"></div> 
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="rang7input" name="rang7value">
</td>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

**And these are the draggable images (images you can drag) they come from a database and have different id's:**

```
<td> <?php echo "<img class='DraggedItem' id='".$row["IDPictogram"]."' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($row['Pictogram'])."' width='90' height='90' draggable='true'>"; ?> </td>
```

**This is the php code:**

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$rang1 = $_POST["rang1value"];
$rang2 = $_POST["rang2value"];
$rang3 = $_POST["rang3value"];
$rang4 = $_POST["rang4value"];
$rang5 = $_POST["rang5value"];
$rang6 = $_POST["rang6value"];
$rang7 = $_POST["rang7value"];
$bewonerID = $_POST["bewoner"];

echo "<script>alert('Rang1: $rang1')</script>";
echo "<script>alert('Rang2: $rang2')</script>";
echo "<script>alert('Rang3: $rang3')</script>";
echo "<script>alert('Rang4: $rang4')</script>";
echo "<script>alert('Rang5: $rang5')</script>";
echo "<script>alert('Rang6: $rang6')</script>";
echo "<script>alert('Rang7: $rang7')</script>";
}
```

**First problem:** As you can see in my script above I used "helper: 'clone'" but the images
 with the class".DraggedItem" are being moved and this is not the point. The images are supposed to be moved and replaced between the 7 divs. But they are supposed to be cloned from the original list (so i can use the same icon twice e.g)
**Second problem:**  I have a hidden input for each div and they must contain the id of the 
dropped image so i can insert them into a database. Let's just say I dropped an image on Div1 (#rang1), and then moved the image to Div4 (#rang4), the id of the image remains in the hidden input of the Div1 and not get deleted/updated. How can I make sure that the id also gets updated when I drop a new image on the div?
**Third problem:** how can I do a check when I drop an image from the main list, that if there is already an image, the old image gets deleted and replaced by the new one?
[image]

**Fourth problem:**  what is the best way to switch between 2 images?
[image]

If you can help me with any of these problems it would be much appreciated!! I can't go further without solving these problems and I really need help from experts.

Comment: Building a jsFiddle to test. You're looking to drag&drop a clone to one of the 7 spots? http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

Comment: @Twisty I'll build an example in jsFiddle, wait pls :)

Comment: @Twisty I updated the question. You'll see a demo above the question.

Comment: Posted an answer and a fork of your jsFiddle. That really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with some refactoring of the code to get rid of all copy-paste code. Droppables can be initialised with a single call, referencing each input within the callback as `$(this).next('input')`.

Next, I would not clone the images directly into the dropped fields to avoid ID duplication. I'd create new image elements with a different class inside the slots, as they have to behave differently when moved between slots, in my example without a translucent helper.

So in my example, you have your `DraggedItem` images without changes. I added the `DropZone` class to each droppable slot to allow initialisation with a single call.

When an image is dropped, I check where it came from. If it came from the library, create a new image element, set its `src` to match the original and set the `data-id` data attribute to the original item's ID for keeping track if needed. As a final step, I add a `DroppedItem` class and make it another kind of draggable without a helper.

If the item dropped is a `DroppedItem`, i.e. came from a different slot, simply swap the contents of the containers and the corresponding `input` box values.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang1" class="DropZone"></div> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang1input" name="rang1value" />
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang2" class="DropZone"></div> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang2input" name="rang2value" />
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang3" class="DropZone"></div> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang3input" name="rang3value" />
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang4" class="DropZone"></div> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang4input" name="rang4value" />
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang5" class="DropZone"></div>
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang5input" name="rang5value" />
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang6" class="DropZone"></div> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang6input" name="rang6value" />
        </td>
        <td> 
            <div id="rang7" class="DropZone"></div> 
            <input type="text" value="" id="rang7input" name="rang7value" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<img id="img1" class="DraggedItem" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=1" />
<img id="img2" class="DraggedItem" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=2" />
<img id="img3" class="DraggedItem" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=3" />
<img id="img4" class="DraggedItem" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=4" />
<img id="img5" class="DraggedItem" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=5" />
<img id="img6" class="DraggedItem" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=6" />
<img id="img7" class="DraggedItem" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=7" />
```

**CSS**

```
table { margin-bottom: 50px; }
td div { width: 50px; height: 50px; border:1px solid silver; margin-bottom: 10px;}
td input { width: 50px; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.DraggedItem').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor:'move',
    opacity: 0.7
});

var droppedOptions = {
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move'
};

$('.DropZone').droppable({
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);

        if(ui.draggable.is('.DroppedItem')) {
            // Item is dragged from another slot, swap images

            var draggedFrom = ui.draggable.parent();
            droppedOn.find('img').appendTo(draggedFrom);
            dropped.css({ top:0, left:0 }).appendTo(droppedOn);

            var temp = '' + droppedOn.next('input').val();
            draggedFrom.next('input').val(temp);
            droppedOn.next('input').val(dropped.data('id'));
        } else {
            // Item is dragged from library

            droppedOn
                .empty() // Delete already dropped items
                .next('input')
                    .val(dropped.attr('id'));

            $('<img class="DroppedItem">')
                .attr('src', dropped.attr('src'))
                .data('id', dropped.attr('id'))
                .draggable(droppedOptions)
                .appendTo(droppedOn);
        }
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bLbxbmck/3/)

Note that in my example I changed the input type to `text` for display, just change it back to `hidden` an you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:
https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/rdxmmobe/3/

```
$(function () {
    $(".DraggedItem").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        opacity: 0.7,
        revert: true
    });

    $("div[id^='rang']").droppable({
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
            var target = $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "input");
            target.val($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
            var dropCopy = $("<img>");
            console.log("Setting DropCopy Source: " + $(ui.draggable).attr('src'));
            $(dropCopy).attr('src', $(ui.draggable).attr('src'));
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            droppedOn.append(dropCopy).css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It's not really solving the problem as it should but I appreciate your effort. ^^
Thank you again!

Comment: Well, I hope my example can help you improve your code some. 1 function for many elements can make your life happier.